# How do I write VB Inline html templates in Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, templates, razor

I am struggling with writing in-line templates in razor vb.

Here is a sample forms c# version.  Can someone translate to RAZOR vb?

```
 <%Html.GridView<Employee>(
      this.ViewData.Model,
      data => { %>
        <table class="grid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</td>
                <th>&nbsp;</td>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
            </tr>
      <% },
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear, even in the latest Visual Studio, that this was supported, which is very unfortunate.  It does seem templates are supported to some degree (as taken from [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1657902.aspx?Razor%20Inline%20Template%20Item%20Keyword%20in%20VB)), but not for complex control setups like you have above.  Bummer.